# Docker в php приложениях

Tags: php, yii2, docker, docker-compose

Начал осваивать Docker. Есть два образа: на основе первого инициализируется контейнер с Php + Apache + монтируется том с php приложением( yii2 ) + ставится Composer и Git, на основе второго - Mysql. Все это делаю через Docker-compose.

**Содержимое docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_template
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: мне необходимо применить миграции, запустив команду "php yii migrate". В контейнере с Php у меня нет Mysql, поэтому Yii2 выдаст ошибку при запуске миграций. А в контейнере с Mysql у меня нет Php и монтированного образа. Что делать в этой ситуации? Правильно ли я понимаю, что я не могу подключиться к Mysql изнутри контейнера с Php?

Comment: Смотря как подключаетесь, если через юникс соккет, то php его не найдет. Подключайтесь по ip адресу того контейнера, где крутиться mysql, а он должен быть сконфигурирован на подключение с внешних сетей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать **networks**, подробнее можно почитать здесь https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks

```
services:
    app:
        build: .
        volumes:
          - ./app:/var/www/html
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        networks:
          - nw_internal
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        expose:
          - "3306"
        networks:
          - nw_internal
        environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
           MYSQL_DATABASE: docker_template
networks:
    nw_internal:
```

Тогда контейнер сервиса **db** будет доступен по имени из контейнера **app**, а MySQL будет доступен в **db:3306**

Comment: он и так будет доступен по сетке по умолчанию

Comment: из вопроса я понял, что links работает как-то другому. ладно, ok ) буду знать